# npm behind not working behind cntml proxy

Tags: angularjs, node.js, proxy, npm, reverse-proxy

due to proxy auth problems i use cntml to redirect our proxy over the cntml proxy.
An npm install is terribly slow (takes hours on quickstart project)

I set up npm proxy with this:

```
npm config set proxy http://localhost:1111
npm config set https-proxy http://localhost:1111
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
```

CNTML works for very fast e.g. for chrome.
What can cause npm to fail?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working behind a corporate proxy, providing just the host:port may not be enough.  I have found success with the following steps:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false

npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

*Below, the %5C is a replacement of the backslash, and is important*

```
npm config set proxy http://<domain>%5C<username>:   
<password>@<host>:<port>

npm config set https-proxy http://<domain>%5C<username>:
<password>@<host>:port

npm install <npm_package>
```

Here is an example of the proxy usage:

```
npm config set proxy http://MyDomain%5CMyUsername:
MyPassword@myproxy.mycorp.net:1234
```